# Query for a value inside array and update(index not known) in mongodb php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to query for a particular value inside array and update it and i dont know the index. Here are the contents.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b1100000f")
"employment_details" : [
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000015"),
     "title" : "Information Technology Compliance & Security",
     "rank" : null,
     "department" : null,
     "current" : false,
     "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de941001d19d")
 }
......
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000018"),
     "title" : "security engineer",
     "rank" : null,
     "department" : null,
     "current" : false,
     "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de941001dasd")
 }
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b11000016"),
     "title" : "software Engineer",
     "rank" : null,
     "department" : null,
     "current" : true,
     "company_id" : ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de94100189e")
}  
]
```

I want to change the particular **current** field of particular object inside array(i dont know the index) inside **employment_details** if **_id** matches **ObjectId("50072b17b4a6de3b1100000f")** and **company_id** matches **ObjectId("5007269fb4a6de94100189e")**.

Here is what I ve done. But not updating.

```
$criteria = array("_id" => $mongo_id, "employment_details.company_id" => $company_id);
$new_object = array('$set' => array('employment_details.$.current' => "false", "updated_at" => $time));
$mycollection->update($criteria,$new_object);
```

How to do such a update?

Comment: Are you sure your criteria finds something? Is it possible that you are not encapsulating the two ids in `MongoId` objects?

Comment: They are sure mongoID's. What I am trying is not working. That's y asking for a method to work. @Sammaye

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your method, the positional operator should work just fine in that query. There must be something wrong with the query if it is not working.

Comment: sorry.. my mistake in the query. @Sammaye

Comment: I would recommend running these from the mongo shell crud prompt when it doesn't do what you want, then you can interactively play around and get it working and then go back to your program